# Evaluating a complex expression

Tags: complex

I have the function complex valued function    
 **g[z_]:=(2a z^2+bz)/(az^2+bz)** where $z=e^{i \theta}$.I want g in terms of $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$.How do I do it mathematica?Next I want value(s) of $\theta$for which the expression $g$ is real and greater than 1.Could somebody kindly help

Comment: Use `ExpToTrig[z]`.

Comment: I tried **ComplexExpand[ExpToTrig[(2*a* z^2+b.z)/(a.z^2+b.z) ]]** but I am not getting real and imaginary parts of the expression.Could you kindlu help

Comment: ExpToTrig[expression] is working though

Comment: The way you have it written, `bz` does not equal `b*z` if that is what you trying for.

Comment: Please improve your post based on feedback you have received and stay responsive to the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
z = E^(I*\[Theta])

g[z_] = (2 a z^2 + b z)/(a z^2 + b z)
```

Note I separated az and bz assuming that is what you want.

The imaginary part of `g[z]`.

```
Im[g[z]] // ComplexExpand // Simplify
(*(a b Sin[\[Theta]])/(a^2 + 2 a b Cos[\[Theta]] + b^2)*)
```

g[z] will be real when `Sin[\[Theta]] =0`, so theta will be `n Pi` with n an integer or `0`

The real part

```
R = Re[g[z]] // ComplexExpand // Simplify
(*(2 a^2 + 3 a b Cos[\[Theta]] + b^2)/(a^2 + 2 a b Cos[\[Theta]] + b^2)*)
```

Knowing nothing about `a` and `b`, although we have previously assumed they are real, its hard to say what values of theta will make `g>1`.

If you assign those values, you can use

```
Reduce[R > 1, \[Theta]]
```